# PHPMailer not able to send send email with ec2

Tags: email, amazon-ec2, phpmailer, sendgrid, amazon-ses

I'm using **PHPmailer** to send account verification mail, I'm using **AWS ec2** instance, however, that mailer is working fine in **localhost** but when I upload that to **server** emails are not going, 
at first, i used **SendGrid** credentials to send emails, failed, then tried **Gmail SMTP**, failed, and somewhere I read that ec2 can't send emails, then I created **SES** also, still can't able to send.

searched on the web abt that but no answers are fixing my problem,

in **localhost**, in can send emails with the same code and with **SendGrid** of Gmail credentials, why I can't send with the server?

my PHP mailer code is:

```
$sub = "Thankyou For registration! Confirm Your mail to Login";
$mailBody = "<h1>You are successfully registered<br />Visit site to login</h1>";

require 'mailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isSMTP();                                   // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = "tls://email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com";                    // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                            // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = "smtp_username";          // SMTP username
$mail->Password = "smtp_password"; // SMTP password
// $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                         // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 465;                                 // TCP port to connect to

$mail->setFrom("my_mail_id@gmail.com", "SMTP_REPLAY_NAME");
$mail->addReplyTo("my_mail_id@gmail.com", "SMTP_REPLAY_NAME");
$mail->addAddress("recipient_mail_id@gmail.com");   // Add a recipient

$mail->isHTML(true);  // Set email format to HTML
$mail->Subject = $sub;
$mail->Body    = $mailBody;
if(!$mail->send()) {
echo 'Message could not be sent.';
} else {
echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

it shows **Message has been sent** but I cant receive emails, checked in **spam** folder also, no clue of mail!

even I have openSSL certificate also! opened SMTP port for both inbound and outbound in **security group** of ec2, everything working fine but **PHPMailer**!

Comment: AWS is currently experiencing service outages: https://status.aws.amazon.com/

Comment: now Asian region servers are up, and I'm using SendGrid for SMPT (for now), not S3

Comment: thank you i did debug and found answer [here](https://gistpages.com/posts/phpmailer_smtp_error_failed_to_connect_to_server_permission_denied_13_fix)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get your protocols straight. In the `Host` you're specifying `tls`, but telling it to connect to `Port = 465`, which will not work with TLS. Either change your `Port` to `587` (preferred) or change your encryption method to `ssl`. Enabling debug output (`SMTPDebug = 2`) will let you in on what's happening in the conversation with the server.

A perusal of [the troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting) would probably help.

Comment: I tried with both SSL and TLS with port 465 and 587. As I said mails are sending and I'm receiving those mails when I'm using in localhost

Comment: changed those settings again, but message is showing success but mail I can't receive yet!!

Comment: So what does the debug output say? Add it to your question.

Comment: How to get debug report? Tried with try-catch method. That also showing success message only

Comment: Read the guide. It tells you.

Comment: thank you, my mailer httpd mail sending was off, with your answer i used debug and found answer

[here](https://gistpages.com/posts/phpmailer_smtp_error_failed_to_connect_to_server_permission_denied_13_fix)